# segmentation fault core dumped with structs

Tags: c++

I am having a lot of warning and when i compile i get a segmentation fault core dumped. I am sure it has something to do with the pointers or declarations.

```
struct Item
{
char *type;
char *name;
double *price;
double quantity;
};

int main(){

struct Item cart[3];
struct Item book[4];
struct Item clothing[5];
struct Item sports[6];
book->name = "harry potter";
strcpy(book->price,  "100");
clothing->name = "shirt";
strcpy(clothing->price, "15");
sports->name = "football";
strcpy(sports->price, "20");
scanf("enter Item %c", cart->type);
if (cart->type == "book"){
   scanf("please enter quantity %d", book->quantity);
   printf("%s %d %d", book->name, book->price, book->quantity);
}
if (cart->type == "clothing"){
   scanf("please enter quantity %d", clothing->quantity);
       printf("%s %d %d", clothing->name, clothing->price, clothing- >quantity);
}
if (cart->type == "sports"){
   scanf("please enter quantity %d", sports->quantity);
       printf("%s %d %d", sports->name, sports->price, sports->quantity);
}
}
```

Comment: No offense, but this code is broken in far too many ways for anyone to provide a good answer. You need to re-review whatever book/class you are working on.

Answer (score 0):

You should not ignore compiler warnings. The compiler has a very good reason for issuing these warnings.

```
strcpy(book->price,  "100");
```

The `price` member is a pointer `double *`. It is not initialized either. This attempts to copy a character string into an uninitialized pointer to a `double`.

This code will likely crash on this, the very first, statement.

Additionally `book` is an array. It is not a pointer:

```
struct Item cart[3];
struct Item book[4];
struct Item clothing[5];
struct Item sports[6];
```

This declares `cart` as an array of three `Item`s, `book` as an array of 4 `Item`s, and so on. It is true that `book` decays to a pointer to an `item`, but whatever you were trying to accomplish here, it can't be right.

```
strcpy(sports->price, "20");
```

More undefined behavior. The `price` class member is not initialized, and it is a pointer to a `double`, into which you attempt to `strcpy()` a character string. Not going to work.

```
sports->name = "football";
```

A little bit better, but still wrong. `name` is a `char *`. A string literal is a `const char *`. The compiler is rightfully warning you about losing the `const` qualifier here.

```
if (cart->type == "book")
```

No matter how you went about initializing `type`, this is unlikely to ever evaluate to true, unless the compiler/linker merges duplicate string literals.

This compares the raw pointer address of the `type` class member with the address of the "book" string literal. Even if `type` was pointing to the string "book", this will evaluate to false, until it happens to be the same string literal. For this to ever possibly evaluate to `true`, a number of dominoes must fall in the right direction:

1) The linker must merge identical string literals

2) `type` must be initialized, somewhere, by an assignment from another literal string "type".

```
scanf("please enter quantity %d", book->quantity);
```

There are two different errors here. First, conversion parameters to `scanf()` must be passed by their address, using the `&` operator. Additionally, `quantity` is a `double`, and will not work with the "%d" `int` conversion specifier.

There are simply too many problems here, to make it even possible to guess what this code should be doing.

I think it's quite impressive that your compiler actually managed to compile this, without erroring out and refusing to generate an object file, with all these problems. Whatever compiler is this, I hope I never have to use it. I expect my compiler to yell at me, loudly, if what I do is even slightly wrong.